# Calculating 2 particle Partial Trace for Density Matrix in Zeeman basis for a large number of Spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

I want to trace out all spins but 2 from a density matrix in the zeeman basis for N spins. For N=3 for example I would have the basisvectors:
$ |S=1.5, m=-1.5\rangle =|000\rangle, |S=1.5, m=1.5\rangle =|111\rangle, |S=1.5, m=0.5\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt(3)}(|110\rangle + |101\rangle + |011\rangle), |S=1.5, m=-0.5\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt(3)}(|001\rangle + |010\rangle + |100\rangle),$

Now it is straightforward for a density matrix $\rho$ to just trace out the third spin, since the partial trace does not depend on the basis :
$$ \rho_{1,2} = \langle1|_3\rho|1\rangle_3 + \langle0|_3\rho|0\rangle_3$$

Obviously the terms from the different basis vectors mix and add up. It is not as simple as just adding up diagonal elements. My problem is, that I need to do this for very large systems numerically and I can't seem to find a pattern, which would let me easily use this for say 10 spins. (I don't want to do it by hand since 10 spins lead to a 11x11 density matrix assuming Spin is conserved.)

Any tips or tricks I might not know?

Comment: I think you should clear up on the density matrix concept first, because expecting an 11x11 matrix for 10 spins doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm only looking at one spin block, but it doesn't matter, I got it now.